# Get records from table by two datetime columns

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have table which name is `category_video`. I want to get record between `broadcast_date` and `broadcast_enddate`. If current time matches between `broadcast_date` and `broadcast_enddate` all records are displayed.

My query is here:

```
$date = date("m/d/Y h:i:s");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category_video WHERE ('".$date."' BETWEEN broadcast_date AND broadcast_enddate)");
```

Suppose I insert one record `broadcast_date` is `04/11/2015 09:00:00` and `broadcast_enddate` 04/11/2015 11:00:00

Please help me how to get this record.

Comment: Start saving datetimes in DATETIME fields, and your life will become much easier. Like: ... NOW() BETWEEN start AND end ...

Comment: OP: how can start date be higher than end datetime?